# Showing graph on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, plotly

I'm working on a project for a time attendance system. Basically, I have a user registration system with admin verification. In the admin panel, I want to show working hours of workers by dates. I'm using Plotly.js for that. The problem is when I call `onClick` function by clicking button without adding return false; my graph disappears after a few seconds. If I add return false, then the graph shows; however, if I want to change to other worker, then the graph won't show and it would go wide right.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
// Include config file
require_once "conn.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin pregled korisnika</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif;}
    .wrapper {
            width: 420px; padding: 20px;
            text-align:center;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 5%;
            width: 45%;
            margin-top: 10%;
            background-color: #191970   ;
            border-radius: 20px;
            box-shadow:20px 20px 30px grey;
            color:white;
    }
    .right {
        float:right;
    }
    #myPlot{width:40%;overflow:visible;margin-top:10%;}
    #users {
        //font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #users td, th {
        border: 1px solid #191970;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    
    #users tr{background-color: white;color:#191970}
    
    
    #users th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #191970;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #191970;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        li {
            float: right;
            height:100%;
            border-left: 1px solid white;
            
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 26px 33px;
            text-decoration: none;
            height:100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        li a:hover{
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            color:#191970;
            text-decoration: none;
            height:100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .dugme{
            margin: auto 3%;
            background-color: #191970;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-color: #191970;
        }
        .dugme:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: #191970;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-color: #191970;
            border-radius: 4px;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul> 
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/E0uimCR.png" height="58" alt="CoolBrand">
        </a>
        <li><b><a href="logout.php">ODJAVI SE</a></b></li>
        <li><b><a href="admin.php">ADMIN</a></b></li>
    </ul>
    
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <h1>Pregled korisnika: </h1>

    <table id = "users">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Korisničko ime</th>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Prezime</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE stat = 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td>
                <form action ="aktivnosti.php" method ="POST">
                    <button class="dugme" onclick="getVrijeme(); return false;" name  ="uname" value = "<?php echo $row['uname'];?>"/><?php echo $row['uname'];?></button>
                    
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ime'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['prezime'];?></td>
        </tr>
    

    <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
</div>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    require_once "conn.php";
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $string1 = $string2 = $string3 = "";
    $mysqli_qry = "SELECT * FROM $uname";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$mysqli_qry);
    if ($br=mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $string1 = $string1. $row["datum"] . "*";
        $string2= $string2. $row["vrijemerada"] . "*";
    }
}

}
?>

<div class="right"><div id="myPlot"></div></div>
    <script>
        function getVrijeme(){
    var data1 = <?php echo json_encode($string1,JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;
    var data2 = <?php echo json_encode($string2,JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;
    var poz1=[];
    var poz2=[];
    var j=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
        if(data1[i]=='*'){
            poz1[j++]=i;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data2.length;i++){
        if(data2[i]=='*'){
            poz2[j++]=i;
        }
    }
    var radnovr=[];
    var datumi=[];
    radnovr[0]=data1.substring(0,poz1[0]);
    datumi[0]=data2.substring(0,poz2[0]);
    for(i=1;i<poz1.length;i++){
        radnovr[i]=data1.substring(poz1[i-1]+1,poz1[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<poz2.length;i++){
        datumi[i]=data2.substring(poz2[i-1]+1,poz2[i]);
    }
    var data = [{
        x: radnovr,
        y: datumi,
        type: "bar",
        }];
    var layout = {
        xaxis: {title: "Datumi"},
        yaxis: {title: "Provedeni sati"},
        title: "Provedeni sati na dnevnom nivou.",
        plot_bgcolor: "white",
        paper_bgcolor: "white"
    };

    Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: view source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin pregled korisnika</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif;}
    .wrapper {
            width: 420px; padding: 20px;
            text-align:center;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 5%;
            width: 45%;
            margin-top: 10%;
            background-color: #191970   ;
            border-radius: 20px;
            box-shadow:20px 20px 30px grey;
            color:white;
    }
    .right {
        float:right;
    }
    #myPlot{width:40%;overflow:visible;margin-top:10%;}
    #users {
        //font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #users td, #customers th {
        border: 1px solid #191970;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    
    #users tr{background-color: white;color:#191970}
    
    
    #users th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #191970;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #191970;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        li {
            float: right;
            height:100%;
            border-left: 1px solid white;
            
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 26px 33px;
            text-decoration: none;
            height:100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        li a:hover{
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #191970;
            color:#191970;
            text-decoration: none;
            height:100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .dugme{
            margin: auto 3%;
            background-color: #191970;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-color: #191970;
        }
        .dugme:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: #191970;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-color: #191970;
            border-radius: 4px;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul> 
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/E0uimCR.png" height="58" alt="CoolBrand">
        </a>
        <li><b><a href="logout.php">ODJAVI SE</a></b></li>
        <li><b><a href="admin.php">ADMIN</a></b></li>
    </ul>
    
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <h1>Korisnici koji čekaju dozvolu: </h1>

    <table id = "users">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Korisničko ime</th>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Prezime</th>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <form action ="aktivnosti.php" method ="POST">
                    <button class="dugme" onclick="getVrijeme(); return false;" name  ="uname" value = "marko"/>marko</button>
                    
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>marko</td>
            <td>srbin</td>
        </tr>
    

            <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
                <form action ="aktivnosti.php" method ="POST">
                    <button class="dugme" onclick="getVrijeme(); return false;" name  ="uname" value = "vale"/>vale</button>
                    
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>eee</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
        </tr>
    

            <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
                <form action ="aktivnosti.php" method ="POST">
                    <button class="dugme" onclick="getVrijeme(); return false;" name  ="uname" value = "dudule"/>dudule</button>
                    
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>duuuu</td>
            <td>leee</td>
        </tr>
    

                </table>
</div>


<div class="right"><div id="myPlot"></div></div>
    <script>
        function getVrijeme(){
    var data1 = "2021-11-04 *2021-11-05 *2021-11-06 *2021-11-07 *2021-11-08 *";
    var data2 = "3*4*2*1*5*";
    var poz1=[];
    var poz2=[];
    var j=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
        if(data1[i]=='*'){
            poz1[j++]=i;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data2.length;i++){
        if(data2[i]=='*'){
            poz2[j++]=i;
        }
    }
    var radnovr=[];
    var datumi=[];
    radnovr[0]=data1.substring(0,poz1[0]);
    datumi[0]=data2.substring(0,poz2[0]);
    for(i=1;i<poz1.length;i++){
        radnovr[i]=data1.substring(poz1[i-1]+1,poz1[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<poz2.length;i++){
        datumi[i]=data2.substring(poz2[i-1]+1,poz2[i]);
    }
    var data = [{
        x: radnovr,
        y: datumi,
        type: "bar",
        }];
    var layout = {
        xaxis: {title: "Datumi"},
        yaxis: {title: "Provedeni sati"},
        title: "Provedeni sati na dnevnom nivou.",
        plot_bgcolor: "white",
        paper_bgcolor: "white"
    };

    Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
}
    </script>
```

Comment: OK - the default behaviour for a `button` is to `submit` the form that it is contained within which explains using `return false` allowing the chart to remain visible. There was another issue was with the CSS but I cannot remember what that was now ~ nothing major but affect the layout as you noted.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The problem is not first use of button. On first click, it works excellent - (https://i.imgur.com/HDWj77y.png), but if I want to show the chart for another user, and click on his username, it should just update the graph with values for that user, but it doesn't work. doing this (https://i.imgur.com/EyE0Z3s.png). Throwing it more right, and not updateing the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not a solution you might be able to work with this to proceed. The first and subsequent clicks do not now modify the page layout drastically as before and I have no doubt with some tweaks you'll get the layout you need/want.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.dugme').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',getVrijeme))

function getVrijeme() {
  var data1 = "2021-11-04 *2021-11-05 *2021-11-06 *2021-11-07 *2021-11-08 *";
  var data2 = "3*4*2*1*5*";
  var poz1 = poz2 = [];
  var j;
  
  j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    if(data1[i] == '*') poz1[j++] = i;
  }
  
  
  j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    if(data2[i] == '*') poz2[j++] = i;
  }
  
  var radnovr = [data1.substring(0, poz1[0])];
  var datumi = [data2.substring(0, poz2[0])];

  
  for (i = 1; i < poz1.length; i++) {
    radnovr[i] = data1.substring(poz1[i - 1] + 1, poz1[i]);
  }
  for (i = 1; i < poz2.length; i++) {
    datumi[i] = data2.substring(poz2[i - 1] + 1, poz2[i]);
  }
  
  
  var data = [{
    x: radnovr,
    y: datumi,
    type: "bar",
  }];
  
  
  var layout = {
    xaxis: { title: "Datumi" },
    yaxis: { title: "Provedeni sati" },
    title: "Provedeni sati na dnevnom nivou.",
    plot_bgcolor: "white",
    paper_bgcolor: "white"
  };

  Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
}
```

```css
body,body *{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  width:100%;height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  width:80%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin:10% auto 0 1rem;
  background-color: #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px grey;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper > div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.wrapper > div > #users,
.wrapper > div > #myPlot{
  flex:1;
  align-self:flex-start;
  margin:1rem;
}


td > form > button{ width:80%; margin:0 auto; float:none; text-align:center; }










#users {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#users td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #191970;
  padding: 8px;
}
#users tr {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970
}
#users th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.dugme {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #191970;
}
.dugme:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #191970;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Korisnici koji čekaju dozvolu: </h1>
  <div>
    <table id="users">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Korisničko ime</th>
        <th>Ime</th>
        <th>Prezime</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <form action="aktivnosti.php" method="POST">
            <button type='button' class="dugme" name="uname" value="marko">marko</button>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td>marko</td>
        <td>srbin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
          <form action="aktivnosti.php" method="POST">
            <button type='button' class="dugme" name="uname" value="vale">vale</button>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <form action="aktivnosti.php" method="POST">
            <button type='button' class="dugme" name="uname" value="dudule">dudule</button>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td>duuuu</td>
        <td>leee</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="myPlot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```